# CloudFormation Stack to modify a resource already created by another stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a step function stateMachine which will be used to invoke a lambda, but is there a way to populate the arn of the lambda later because the lambda is a part of another CloudFormation stack which is triggered later.

Please refer to the below code snippet:

Snippet from stack template 1:

```js
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Resources:
  ExampleStateMachine:
    Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
    Properties:
      DefinitionString: ${file(cloudformation/resources/state-machine-definitions/example.yaml)}
      DefinitionSubstitutions:
        functionArn: ''
      RoleArn: !GetAtt ExampleStateMachineRole.Arn
      StateMachineName: ${self:custom.stage}ExampleStateMachine
      StateMachineType: STANDARD
Outputs:
  ExampleStateMachineRoleArn:
    Description: The ARN of the role created for the exampleStateMachine
    Value: !GetAtt ExampleStateMachineRole.Arn
    Export:
      Name: ${env:RESOURCE_PREFIX}:${self:custom.featureName-stage}:ExampleStateMachineRoleArn
  ExampleStateMachineName:
    Description: Name of the state machine created for partners life submit referral retry
    Value: !GetAtt ExampleStateMachine.Name
    Export:
      Name: ${env:RESOURCE_PREFIX}:${self:custom.featureName-stage}:ExampleStateMachineName
 
 /* state machine definition yaml (example.yaml) */
 
 |-
  {
      "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
      "StartAt": "Lambda Invoke",
      "States": {
        "Lambda Invoke": {
          "Type": "Task",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
          "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
          "Parameters": {
            "Payload.$": "$",
            "FunctionName": "${functionArn}"
          },
          "Retry": [
            {
              "ErrorEquals": [
                "States.ALL"
              ],
              "IntervalSeconds": 60,
              "MaxAttempts": 15,
              "BackoffRate": 1
            }
          ],
          "End": true
        }
      }
    }
```

Snippet from stack template 2:

```js
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Resources:
  # modifies the definition string of the state machine to point to the lambda
  ExampleStateMachine:  //Does not work because this resource is already created as a part of the previous stack
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
    Properties:
      DefinitionString: ${file(../infrastructure/core/cloudformation/resources/state-machine-definitions/example.yaml)}
      DefinitionSubstitutions:
        functionArn: !GetAtt ExampleLambdaFunction.Arn //this is what I am trying to update
      RoleArn: !ImportValue ${env:RESOURCE_PREFIX}:${self:custom.featureName-stage}:ExampleStateMachineRoleArn
      StateMachineName: !ImportValue ${env:RESOURCE_PREFIX}:${self:custom.featureName-stage}:ExampleStateMachineName
```

Comment: Is the name of the lambda function dynamic? Does it have to be created after the state machine?

Comment: Hello @tianz, yes. The lambda is deployed as a part of another stack after the state machine has been deployed.

Comment: Since the lambda is used by the state machine, it really should be deployed before the state machine, otherwise you are creating a circular dependency.